# ng-click not working more than once

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using an ng-click in a dropdown to set a value in another dropdown, but need it to be able to be clicked multiple times in case the user needs to change it.

From my understanding, `ng-click` should be able to be used multiple times. But I can't get it to perform more than once.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
        <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
                Campaign <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
            <li ng-repeat="campaign in int.campaigns">
                <a ng-click="int.getPages(campaign.ID)">{{campaign.Name}}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

And here is my function.

```
vm.getPages = function(campaignID) {

    pageService.getPagesByCampaignId(campaignID)
        .then(function(result) {
                vm.pages = result.data;
                console.log('pages returned');
            },
        function(result) {
           console.log('page return failed');
        });
};
```

I'm a noob so I wouldn't doubt I am missing something simple.

Comment: If you click on the same `a` again, what should happen?

Comment: If I click on a different selection in the dropdown, I'd like it to run the function again with the new value from the ng-repeat.

Comment: So you want to merge the responses of 2 clicks or the second click is not working i.e. once pages are set, irrespective of click on any other campaign, pages are not getting updated

Comment: 2nd click isnt working...your ie. is correct.

Comment: Add a log in the `getPages` function as the first line, and see is it getting logged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it inadvertently by adding additional functionality.

I bound the header of the dropdown button to the selected value and now I can continue selecting different options.

```
vm.getPages = function (campaignID, campaign) {
                vm.campaignNameDisplay = campaign.Name;
                pageService.getPagesByCampaignId(campaignID)
                    .then(function (result) {
                        vm.pages = result.data;
                        console.log('pages returned');
                    },
                    function (result) {
                        console.log('page return failed');
                    });
            };
```

and this.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
        <div class="btn-group" uib-dropdown is-open="status.isopen">
            <button id="single-button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" uib-dropdown-toggle ng-disabled="disabled">
                {{int.campaignNameDisplay}} <span class="caret"></span>
            </button>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" uib-dropdown-menu role="menu" aria-labelledby="single-button">
                <li ng-repeat="campaign in int.campaigns">
                    <a ng-click="int.getPages(campaign.ID, campaign)">{{campaign.Name}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```